# Browser address bar showing IP Address instead of DNS Name

Tags: dns, iis-7, asp.net

We have a website dns is brought from 123-reg and hosted in static IP provided by server intellect. We have developed the site in ASP.net Visual Studio 2010 and deployed IIS 7. Everything is working fine. When we type the DNS name in browser it takes to the site but Browser address bar is showing IP address instead of DNS Name. How to keep the DNS name?

Comment: Use your browser developer tools. Does a request get made for the DNS name and get an HTTP Redirect response? Does that response from from your HTTP server or from an 123-reg forwarding server? Does `dig` show a redirect DNS record?

Answer (score 0):

in the hosting machine's /etc/hosts file alias the DNS name and IP

for ex.

127.0.0.1      localhost.localdomain

fe80::         localhost6.localdomain6

123.46.78.90   example-company.com

Comment: Can you explain why this works? Right now I only understand that it might replace the already properly working DNS resolver. But why would the website content change ?